# How to solve polynomial equation with parameter?

Tags: r, equation-solving

I have a polynomial equation in x with an additional parameter in it. My goal is to solve it with R such that I have x on one side, and the parameter terms on the other. Here is a simplified example:

[image]

Now, I would like R to come up with:

[image]

How to do it?

Comment: I don't think that R is what you want to use for this kind of thing. Mathematic or Maple are better suited.

Comment: Did you mean Mathematica? Do you know any free software to do it with?

Comment: Yes, oops. I meant Mathematica. Glad there is actually an R package for this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using Ryacas package likes the following:

```
require("Ryacas")
x <- Sym("x")
t <- Sym("t")
yacas("Solve(4*x^2*t == 3, x)")
```

Know more about this package in [this link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Ryacas/vignettes/Ryacas.pdf).